# Swift @ について

Tags: swift

Swiftの@とは何ですか？ 調べてもさっぱりわかりません

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiftの`@`は **attribute(属性)** を表すのに使われます。`@`だけに独立した意味があるのではなく、必ず`@属性名`と言う形式で使い、それぞれの属性名ごとに、どんな場所に使えるのか・どんな意味を持つのかが異なってきます。

公式であれば

[Attributes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html)

日本語の情報であれば、「swift attribute 一覧」あたりで検索すれば良いでしょう。

例えば、以下のような記事がヒットしました。

[Swift5.1のattribute全解説｜全27種](https://qiita.com/shtnkgm/items/2cba98b545c913d990bc)

上記の日本語記事が大変コンパクトかつしっかりとまとまっていますので、内容をご確認の上、特に詳細を知りたいと言うものがあれば、個別にご質問していただければ良いだろうと思います。

(attributeという単語は色々訳し方があるのですが、「属性」と言う言い方はその記事に合わせました。)

Comment: ありがとうございます

Comment: いつも丁寧なご対応を